# Работа с GIT локально?

Tags: git, git-commit

Можно ли просмотреть изменения версий локально, не делая push в удаленный репозиторий? Если можно, то как?

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться с [GitBook](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1) — пошаговым русскоязычным руководством по git.

Comment: @Arhad она называется "Pro Git", а [GitBook](https://www.gitbook.com/) это нечто совсем другое :)

Answer (score 12):

История коммитов:

```
# в текущей ветке
git log

# Если хотите посмотреть изменения во всех ветках в красивом виде:
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

Что поменялось в файлах проекта между двумя коммитами, ветками, тегами:

```
# явно сравниваем две ветки
git diff master branch1

# или два коммита
git diff ad72b3 134gf6

# можно сравнить что-то с текущим коммитом:
git diff branch1

# например, сравнить предыдущий коммит:
git diff HEAD^
```

Какие файлы изменились с момента последнего коммита:

```
git status -s
```

Что изменилось в этих файлах с последнего коммита:

```
git diff

# можно указать конкретный файл:
git diff filename
```

Comment: Ветку можно указывать удалённую: `git diff origin/master master`. Это позволит увидеть непосредственно изменения, которые будут залиты после `push`

Comment: @vp_arth да, если после `fetch` смотреть. )

Answer (score 5):

Добрый день!

```
git status
```

Показывает текущий статус (изменения в индексе, изменения не в индексе, сколько коммитов вы не запушили).

```
git log
```

Выводит список коммитов для той ветки, в которой вы находитесь. (Там будут номера коммитов, их названия, автор, дата коммита и т.п.)

```
git branch
```

Покажет вам какие ветки есть у вас в репозитории и на какой вы находитесь сейчас

```
git diff <название файла>
```

Покажет непроиндексированные изменения в файле

Думаю, для начала вам будет достаточно)

Comment: А как именно изменения кода увидеть?Например было до commit-public String MyWord(){String word="HELLO";return word;} а после-public String MyWord(){String word="HELLO2";return word;}-именно-высвечивание или подсказка что изменилось то и то!

Comment: между двумя коммитами

Answer (score 3):

Командой `git log -p` в *bash* прямо высвечиваются красным и зеленым изменения

Comment: По сути тот же `git diff`

Answer (score 2):

Тут уже ответов много, но от себя добавлю.
Просмотр коммитов со списком изменённых файлов:

```
git log --stat
```

Иногда бывает нужно посмотреть какие коммиты  принадлежат текущей ветке. В гите это явно сделать нельзя, но можно сравнить с актуальной веткой.

```
git cherry -v master
```

Какие изменения были сделаны в коммите можно посмотреть ещё и так:

```
git show 99452d955bdb57e7e4f2b09f8ce2fbb6cd56377a
```

Comment: `git log --stat` хорош.

Comment: когда-то меня он частенько выручал )